# Mixed string and numeric value ordering

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM price   
ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2))  
DESC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
```

this query is showing result like that

```
Example
________________________
Product      | Price
________________________
Shoes         | 94,200 
________________________
Shirts        |66,900
________________________
Socks         |59,900
________________________
T-shirt       |49,700
________________________
Shirt Cloth   |Coming Soon
________________________
Shirt pant    |Coming Soon
________________________
Shirt jacket  |Coming Soon
________________________
```

And i want like that

```
Example
________________________
Product      | Price
________________________
Shirt Cloth   |Coming Soon
________________________
Shirt pant    |Coming Soon
________________________
Shirt jacket  |Coming Soon
________________________
Shoes         | 94,200 
________________________
Shirts        |66,900
________________________
Socks         |59,900
________________________
T-shirt       |49,700
________________________
```

how can i do this please help me to fix this issue
thanks

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Comment: Good catch @tadman. OP should change those variables to `?` and prepare the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order by` can have arbitrary expressions:

```
ORDER BY (price = 'Coming Soon') DESC, CAST(price AS decimal(10,2))
```

if price is `Coming Soon`, then `price = 'Coming Soon'` will evaluate to a boolean TRUE. if it's not equal, then it's boolean false. With the `DESC` sorting, teh true values will come first, followed by the false values. And within those true/false blocks, the `CAST(...)` will further sort the actual prices.

Comment: Wow, same for the answer above. I just learned two new SQL tricks.

Comment: well this is showing coming soon result 1st but i have another one more problm CAST(price AS decimal(10,2)) this is showing result Shoes         

Shirts        |6,900

Socks         |5,900

T-shirt       |4,700  T-shirt       |4,900 T-shirt       |4,950 how can i sort out by DESC

Comment: @NobleUplift a nice trick with using a Boolean value is when you want to count the number of times something appears... `SUM(price = 'Coming Soon')` will return the number of times something is Coming Soon because it will sum the number of true occurrences

Comment: because `94,200` is not a valid integer `cast('94,200' AS decimal(10,2))` -> `94.00`.

Comment: You know what's funny? I assumed OP was from Europe, using commas in place of periods. Didn't even think of how this wouldn't work with MySQL.

Comment: just remove the commas from the price e.g. `DESC, CAST( REPLACE(price,',','') AS ...`

Answer (score 4):

you can just do a conditional order by

```
ORDER BY
  CASE price
    WHEN "Coming Soon" THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END ASC,
CAST(REPLACE(price, ',', '') AS decimal(10,2)) DESC
```

the beauty of this is you can have multiple conditions... so lets say you have another value besides Coming Soon, and a number.. something like 'Out Of Stock' you can easily incorporate that into your statement

Comment: This is some awesome SQL right here. Had no idea I could do this until now.

Comment: @NobleUplift haha thanks :) you can do a LOT with conditionals in MySQL.. and User Defined Variables..

Comment: well this is showing coming soon result in 1st but i have another one more problm CAST(price AS decimal(10,2)) this is showing result Shoes Shirts |6,900 Socks |5,900 T-shirt |4,700 T-shirt |4,900 T-shirt |4,950 how can i sort out by  complete DESC order

Comment: @user3162123 what is the number before you cast it?

Comment: listen i have price list example (1st) 98,200 (2nd)85,000 3rd(8,500) forth (8,900) fifth (8,400) and i want like that  (1st) 98,200 (2nd)85,000 3rd(8,900) forth (8,500) fifth (8,400) how can i do this

Comment: @user3162123 try my edited query... you have to remove the commas before casting

Comment: i change the code but it is showing error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Coming' (T_STRING)

Comment: missing an `END` in the `CASE` expression? MySQL has convenient shorthand as an alternative to ANSI-standard CASE: `IF(price='Coming Soon',1,2)`

Comment: @user3162123 try again

Comment: @spencer7593 yea missed the END... since the numbers are always going to be greater than 1 you can just put the cast after the coming soon

Comment: again same error SELECT * FROM mprice  ORDER BY
  CASE price
    WHEN "Coming Soon" THEN 1
    ELSE CAST(REPLACE(price, ',', '') AS decimal(10,2)) DESC LIMIT $from, $max_results

Comment: @user3162123 you forgot to put the END in there... you need to END the CASE statement

Comment: @user3162123 your query should be `SELECT * FROM mprice ORDER BY CASE price WHEN "Coming Soon" THEN 1 ELSE CAST(REPLACE(price, ',', '') AS decimal(10,2)) END DESC LIMIT $from, $max_results `

Comment: @JohnRuddell: If you are going to do it one expression (rather than the two you had before), and it's being ordered in descending order,  you'd need that "Coming Soon" to evaluate to MAX_VALUE rather than 1.

Comment: well thanks now working i copy Marc B and spencer7593 was guide me what i want.

Comment: @spencer7593 yes the OP has DESC so it needs to be in two i guess.